# TV show about a post apocalyptic world

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a TV show in the 2000-2006 period. From the Pilot episode I remember a man trying to get home and then a nuclear bomb explodes. The man might have had some military training.
The only other thing I remember is that he had a green jacket on during the pilot.

Comment: I don't have time for a detailed answer, but it is probably Jericho.

Comment: @Taladris hmmm... looks like it might be it. cant remember the main character looking like that tho but it does ring a bell. if you make it into an answer ill gladly accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to fit with [Jericho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jericho_(2006_TV_series)), a TV show that premièred in 2006. It lasts only two seasons, so it corresponds with your time period.

In the pilot, Jake Green (portrayed by Skeet Ulrich) comes back to Jericho after a 5 year absence, for the funeral of his grandfather. The situation with his family is very tense but the explosion of a nuclear bomb in Denver forces him to stay in Jericho. He uses his past as private military contractor to survive and to prevent Jericho from descending into chaos.

You can see most of the main cast in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ni2I1JN8QM). Jake can be seen driving a car in the video. The colors are not great but it seems his jacket is dark green.

To help you check it is the correct TV show, there are two characters that are difficult to forget:

1. Bonnie Richmond, who helps her brother Stanley at a local farm. She is memorable because she is deaf and not so many shows feature people with this disability.
2. Robert Hawkins, the mysterious new neighbour, portrayed by Lennie James.

Comment: Thank you. This is it. now i know what i will be doing tonight. .-)